# Selenium Protractor - Search from excel

Tags: excel, selenium, npm, protractor

Using Selenium Protractor and  iexceljs for reading excel sheet. its taking too much time is searching a particulate data in big excelsheet. please suggest me some way to improve the execution performance.

We have 3 columns A,B,C  in excel so when data in A and B matches with some data passed from cucumber example you need to fetch c from same row. its working but this comparison is taking too much time.

we have below 3 col in excel and we are passing designation and yr Experience from cucumber example now when Cucumber data nd excel matched we need to fetch emp Name.

```
Designation -   Yr Experience - Emp Name 
 ABCD             -  5       - Tom 
 BCDA             - 4       - Adam
```

Comment: Try using Apache POI instead.  You should also include your code... (though pretty sure your speed issue is due to iexceljs)

Comment: Please include your current code as others have suggested. This will make it clearer for others to help. You might want to consider saving your excel as plain csv instead, so you can just read it in as plaintext.